# How do I spawn a shell sub-command, with its stdout bound to the parent's stdout in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I want a python program to spawn a shell sub-command, with the stdout of the shell being written to the stdout of the python parent.

The python script will be run as a CGI, so the shell output should be sent back to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [python subprocess module docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) tell (emphasis mine)

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and None. PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created. **With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent.** Additionally, stderr can be STDOUT, which indicates that the stderr data from the child process should be captured into the same file handle as for stdout.

So, it should be as easy as

```
subprocess.call(["your_shell_command", /*command line arguments, if any*/])
```

E.g.

```
subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
subprocess.call(["mkdir", "newdir"])
subprocess.call("your_shell_script.sh")
```

Comment: I'd got that, and from the command line it appears to work. My problem is that if I run the .py as a CGI using CGIHTTPServer, I don't get the output.

Comment: subprocess.call('cat /etc/passwd', shell=True)

Comment: @pinoyyid what about CGIHTTPServer related code? And it might make sense to update the question wiht relevant info

Comment: bear with me, I have never used Python before. I assume that CGIHTTPServer is a standard python component, coz I know nothing about it. I just did python -m CGIHTTPServer 8080, created test.py with the one line (subprocess etc) and expected it to just work. I've actually changed direction away from python, so allow me to thank you for your assistance and close this question off.

Comment: @pinoyyid: just add `sys.stdout.flush()` *before* `subprocess.call()`,  [example](http://jfsz.kd.io/python.py).